# Deny Permissions For 'sa' in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In `MS SQL Server Managment Studio |-> sampleDB -> Security -> Users -> New User`
I try to add sa user and in Securables section try to Deny the permission and got error 15405:

> cannot use the special principal 'sa' error 15405

I think i got this error because the sa user already exist in sampleDB users list

Is it possible to deny all permissions for sa user for specific DB ?

problem : I need this because one of the company's of our client by direct manager permission have access to sa user of DBServer ,and i just want to ... you know they don't need our Database information's.

Comment: By definition, `sa` has full rights on the instance. You cannot change this. If you think the solution to your (non-described) problem is to disable `sa`'s rights, you've misanalysed the problem.

Comment: tnx,then there is no solution ,i need this because one of the company's of our client by direct manager permission have access to sa user of DBServer ,and i just want to ... you know they don't need our Database information's.

Comment: Change the password of "sa" login then...

Comment: or disable sa user altogether. anyway you need to grant then backup permission for their backup process unless you are doing that for your client

Comment: Change the password for the sa user and create another login (windows,sql) for the client so that he can still access the database but do lower down the access levels so that his justified demands are met.